# Pandas column dtype is object but python thinks it is float

Tags: python, pandas

I read in a csv like this

```
df = pd.read_csv(self.file_path, dtype=str)
```

then I try this:

```
 df = df[df["MY_COLUMN"].apply(lambda x: x.isnumeric())]
```

I get an AttributeError:

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'

Why is this happening? The column contains mostly digits.

I want to filter out the ones where there are no digits.

This question is not how to achieve that or do it better but why do I get an `AttributeError` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this happening?

I think because NaN is not converting to `string` if use `dtype=str`, still is missing value, so `type=float`

Use [`Series.str.isnumeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html) for working `isnumeric` with missing values like all text functions in pandas:

```
df[df["MY_COLUMN"].str.isnumeric()]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i explicitly am not asking how to do it better or get it working but why i get an error even with stating the dtypes when reading it in.

Comment: @goodsnek - I think because NaN is not converting to `string` if use `dtype=str`